# GitLab CI: How can I reuse installed npm packages between jobs?

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm-install, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages

I have a GitLab Pages site that uses Gulp for building. My .gitlab-ci.yml file looks similar to this:

```
image: node:latest

before_script:
  - npm install gulp-cli -g
  - npm install gulp [...and a whole bunch of packages] --save-dev

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - gulp buildsite
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - gulp
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/
```

Before both the `build` and `pages` jobs, the `npm install` commands are executed (once before each job). Since I have quite a few packages, this usually takes a while.

Is there a way to only do the installs once across the entire build?

I thought that's what `cache` was supposed to help with, but it still seems like it still redownloads everything.

Comment: The cache system doesn't have any guarantees, if you need the node_modules to be sent between jobs 100% of the time, use artifacts http://stackoverflow.com/a/43722345/6654146 You can also add an expiry to the artifacts so they're not kept on your server forever

Answer (score 10):

Though the answer in the comments is essentially correct. I think a specific answer for your case would be good though. One approach you could use is adding a third stage that would bear the load of installing node modules plus you could also cache them to speed up subsequent builds:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - prep
  - build
  - deploy  

before_script:
  - npm install gulp-cli -g  

prep:
  stage: prep
  script:
  - npm install gulp [...and a whole bunch of packages] --save-dev
  artifacts:
   paths:
   - node_modules 
  cache:
   paths:
   - node_modules

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - gulp buildsite
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - gulp
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

This solution will only perform the installation once and will cache the result for future ci pipelines, you may also place an expiry on the node modules artifacts.

Comment: BUG: artifacts will be uploaded by HTTP, so a huge node_modules will result to CI failed by uploading entity too large.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `cache:` [`untracked: true`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cacheuntracked) to really cache the files not tracked by Git.

```
cache:
  untracked: true
  paths:
      - node_modules/
```